# Why does the wireless chip and the ram chip of the pi 3 have squiggly circuits?

Tags: broadcom

I have been looking at my Pi 3 earlier today and I noticed that both the Broadcom chip and the Elpida chip have strange, curvy lines that come in/out of them. I am thinking it may help break up interference with electromagnetism, but I am not sure.

Why are there squiggly lines in the circuits and not straight and sharp like everywhere else on the board?

[image: I don't have a camera on me, so I just pulled the image from https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This style of trace is usually used for impedance matching or timing.

Impedance Matching, because how the traces interact with each other and other components, changing the way the traces make corners and where they are located can change the impedance

Timing:
at 1.2Ghz and moving at the speed of light( in a vacuum) a clock pulse only makes it about 10 inches before the next clock pulse leaves the source.  This means that if you have multiple components that need to be in sync, it can be beneficial to 'delay' a signal by making it go further so that it matches the timing of another device

I did not design this board, so I dont know what the specific reason is here, but those are some options

Comment: Agreed. It's definitely all about trace-tuning.  Here's a really good article on the subject: https://resources.altium.com/pcb-design-blog/high-speed-design-techniques-trace-tuning-for-routing-length-matching